# Wrapping text to the width of an image that isn't set

Tags: jquery, css, image, html, width

I will keep this simple. I have an image that is using the following css:
.img-right {
 float: right;
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 20px;
}

Then I have a caption that lives below the image which is the following css:
.img-right p {
 margin-top: 5px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: #858d93;
}

I want to have the width of the paragraph tag to adjust to the size of the image I am using. The image(s) vary in width that use that class, so I was told the only way to achieve this is through jQuery. Can anyone assist with making this work?

Thanks and Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 0):

Ok try something like this, HTML:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
<img src="foo.jpg" />
<div class="caption">This is my caption</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-wrapper{width:auto; min-width:100px; float:right; margin:0px 0px 10px 20px;}
.img-wrapper img{min-width:100px;}
.img-wrapper .caption{width:auto; min-width:100px; margin-top: 5px; padding-top: 5px; font-size: 11px; color: #858d93; }
```

Comment: I ended up using this jQuery code created by Jared Williams:
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
 $(document).ready(function() {
  height = $('.img-right img').height();
  width  = $('.img-right img').width();
  $('.img-right').find('p').css('width', width); // to set the width of the <p> element
  $('.img-right').css('width', width); //also to set the width of the div containing these things  
 });
// --></script>